Cannot resolve method saveAll
public interface RuleRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Entity, Long> {
  .....
}

private final RuleRepository rulesRepository;
....
rulesRepository.saveAll(....);

I get error:
Cannot resolve method 'saveAll(....)'

Should I change PagingAndSortingRepository to CrudRepository or there is another way to add this method?

For CRUD operation you need a CrudRepeository.
So extend your repository with PagingAndSortingRepository and ListCrudRepository
public interface RuleRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Entity, Long>,ListCrudRepository<Entity, Long>  {
  .....
}

Ref: baeldung spring-data-3-crud-repository-interfaces
